# Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 availability

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

We have a piece of very old code which is not able to compile in latest version of Visual Studio and as my team suggests it badly requires a Visual Studio 2005. We searched in Microsoft community but couldn't find it.

Comment: 2005 fell out of even [extended support almost 3 years ago](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/lifecycle/search/1117). It's beyond time to fix the code base to work in a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2005 can currently only be downloaded when you [have an existing Annual (Standard) Visual Studio subscription](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/). Or you need to find original retail media (DVDs).

[image]

[You can find it here in that case](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202005&pgroup=).

[image]

The latest set of updates [for Visual Studio 2005 can be found here](https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-tfs-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#teamexplorer2005).

Comment: Agreed that making it work with Visual Studio 2015 (at least) or 2019 is highly recommended. I can imagine it may not be easy.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for answering, we tried to make it compatible with VS 2015 but couldn't succeed and since left with no time we purchased the licence.